# Performance Point Filter Problem After Instillation SharePoint 2010 SP1

Tags: sharepoint-2010, performancepoint

I am annoyingly facing Web Control Rendering error after deploying SharePoint 2010 SP1 and Aug 2010 patch. I have created Custom Performance Point Filter as per Pps2010RefSample provided by Microsoft and created a custom rendered class (as `filter.RendererClassName = typeof(CustomFilter).AssemblyQualifiedName;`) instead of `MultiSelectTreeViewControl`.

In this class I simply override the Render method and added only one line:

```
output.Write("<input type='text'ID='myControlID' />");
```

But when I open the Dashboard webpage it throwing me following error:

> > An exception occurred while rendering a Web control. The following diagnostic information might help to determine the cause of this problem:
> >
> > Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BpmException: There was a problem preparing the WebPart for display. PerformancePoint Services error code 20700.

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The filter url in the dashboard designer that populates is wrong, you have to copy and paste the correct location to the webpart filter. /sites//Lists/PerformancePoint Content/1_.000

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

This re-checked but it is not the case. The filter is referenced with correct URL. I found that it was happening due to Farm. My server load balancing was forwarding my request to another server on Farm which do not have access to assembly.

Now the problem is resolved.